# Using two partials in a simple form, params is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that I created using the simple form gem. I created it as a partial and then rendered this partial in my view. However I needed to essentially use the form again in another area of my app.  but unfortunately with the different styling requirements, I wasn't able to us the exact form partial. So I wound up creating a new one, with the only difference having some different stylings associated with it.

However by doing this, the problem happens that I have is that I had to use the same method in my controller as create, which has given me an error stating, `pram is missing or the value is empty:form_submission`

Ultimately, i don't know what param I have that is missing, or I have no way of knowing if the value is empty or not.

Here is my controller. As you can see both `create` and `case_study` are identical.

```
class FormSubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  invisible_captcha only: [:create], on_spam: :handle_spam

  def new
    @form_submission ||= FormSubmission.new
  end

  def create
    @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

    if @form_submission.save
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def case_study
    @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

    if @form_submission.save
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def form_submission_params
      params.require(:form_submission).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :organization, :email, :phone, :recognition, :inquiry)
    end
end
```

My view is called `case_study.html.haml` and I have my partial below

```
= simple_form_for @form_submission do |f|

  .col-md-4.col-md-offset-2
    .field.reco
      = f.input :first_name, input_html: { class: "formStyling" }, label: "First name", required: false
    .field.reco
      = f.input :last_name, input_html: { class: "formStyling" }, label: "Last name", required: false
    .field.reco
      = f.input :phone, input_html: { class: "formStyling" }, label: "Phone", required: false
    %br
    %br
    .col-xs-3.col-xs-offset-4
      = f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-default"
```

Comment: The parameter that's missing is `form_submission`, like it says in the message. It must be generated by simple_form. It looks to me from what you posted like it should be there, so I don't have an answer to your overall question.

Comment: Please post the logs for this action, so that we can see what's being passed from your form to the controller action.

Comment: Your `invisible_captcha` is handling only `create` and not `case_study` action. Can that cause any problems? Also, you don't need to copy/paste your action code. You can simply set the needed url in your simple form using `url: form_submissions_path` option.